# Server error in MVC app due to public property getter/setter

Tags: c#, .net

```
public int IndicationCalculatorGroupId { get; set; }
```

When I have it like that, it works.

```
public int IndicationCalculatorGroupId
    {
        get
        {
            return IndicationCalculatorGroupId;
        }
        set
        {
            IndicationCalculatorGroupId = value;
            SelectList tempList = Chatham.Web.Models.Shared.DropDownData.IndicationsGroup(SessionManager.Company.EntityID, ICConstants.IndicationsCalculatorGroupType);
            foreach (SelectListItem item in tempList)
            {
                if (value.ToString() == item.Value)
                {
                    GroupDisplayName = item.Text;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

That however doesn't seem to work. Basically, I wanted to customize the setter so that when it was set, it would use the value to set it, along with searching for the value in a SelectList to set another property with another value.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Word of caution - property setters with side effects are in general not a great idea. Make sure this behavior is well documented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want custom getter/setter you must create underlying field. Otherwise calls to `IndicationCalculatorGroupId` inside getter will produce StackOverflow.

Comment: @slandau: Yes. This code will cause a `StackOverflowException`. :)